# NetSuite CASE WHEN using LIKE is not working in a formula field. Is there anything similar to use?

Tags: field, formula, admin, netsuite

I am creating a field that is type Integer using the following (this field is intended to check and see if title contains 'refurbished' or not):

`CASE WHEN {custitem_title} LIKE 'Refurbished' THEN 100 ELSE 250 END`

I have also tried

`CASE WHEN {custitem_title} LIKE '%Refurbished%' THEN 100 ELSE 250 END`

and

`CASE WHEN ({custitem_title} LIKE 'Refurbished') THEN 100 ELSE 250 END`

Is this formula type only valid in saved searches? I see recommendations for using 'LIKE' in a 'CASE WHEN' formula all over the internet, but it always pertains to saved searches in NetSuite. Nothing seems to work and I end up with "ERROR: Invalid Expression"
Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with NetSuite, but your attempts look like vanilla SQL, which I *am* familiar with.

Try `CASE WHEN {custitem_title} LIKE '%Refurbished%' THEN 100 ELSE 250 END`

SQL doesn't need anything around a field name unless the field name has spaces. The `LIKE` operator behaves like the `=` operator when you don't include any wildcards (`%` in your case).

Comment: I appreciate it, and I tried your suggestion, but NetSuite still spit out the same error. It does need the {} wrappers in all other instances that I have tried for formulas in NetSuite.

Comment: I added the curly braces. Other than that this was the correct answer regarding like and should be accepted

Comment: @axz3 Are you sure that `custitem_title` is spelled correctly? I would copy/paste it, just to be sure.